# MarkJS does not work on last items in textnode

Tags: javascript, textnode

Using MarkJS, I run into this issue that the last word in the text often does not get highlighted. This happens when I'm using **contenteditable** div but I'm unsure how or when exactly this happens. See how the last 'hellooo' in the second line doesn't get marked?

[image: I was able to replicate my problem using the sample configurator on the official site]

[image: Screenshot from the browser inspector]